# cordova admob in html element

Tags: cordova, webview, admob

Its one of my first posts, so please don't burn me instantly.. :)

I'm using Cordova and am looking for a way to show ads in a 'timeline' kind of fashion (like facebook, posts mixed with random ads). Simply put, a webview with ordinary JS / Angular etc, shows a timeline mixed with ads.

But AdMob only seem to have 'overlay' ads that go on-top of the webview, not 'inside' the webview. On the other hand, Google Adsense isn't allowed in cordova apps so I can just use normal JS ads.

Is there a way to accomplish this with AdMob? Or should I go for another ad company? I can't imagine, with how big advertising is, thats its something really weird i'm trying?

Thanks!

p.s. for a visual context, check www.coinpush.app/#/timeline